# How can one find such probability for this round table problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

$10$ individuals including $x$ and $y$ seat at random at a round table. All possible orders are equally likely. Let $W$ be the event that there are exactly two people seated between $x$ and $y$. What is the probability of this event?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $x$ sits somewhere (it doesn't matter where). There are $9$ seats left. There are $2$ of these seats where $y$ can seat so that there are two people between them. So the answer is $2/9$. In the image bellow these would be the red seats:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
A valid placement is

```
... i-1  i    i+1  i+2  i+3  i+4  ...  
... a    X    b    c    Y    d    ...
```

another is

```
... i-1  i    i+1  i+2  i+3  i+4  ...  
... a    Y    b    c    X    d    ...
```

where $10$ must be subtracted from the seat number $i+k$ if it is larger then $10$.

The first placement is related to the placement

```
1    2   3   4   5 ... 10
X    b   c   Y   d ...  a
```

Annotation:

I thought you want to calculate the number of placements where 2 people are seated between $x$ and $y$. If you have this number you divide it by $10!$ and get the probability that you really want. But of course this probability can be calculated by the way [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4064651/11206) shows us in a simpler way.